# C# javascript dynamic name for application variable

Tags: javascript, c#, variables

I want to create and access application variables using javascript in C# - but I want to create the name dynamically...

```
for (i = 1; i <= 25; i++) {       
 var myAppVariable = "id" + i.toString()
 if (Application(['myAppVariable']) == null) {
  Application(['myAppVariable']) = 0;
  }
}
```

Is this possible?  I'm not sure what to put inside the brackets to properly address myAppVariable.

Thanks!

Comment: I thought I should add my ultimate goal - say I've got a web-based check-in check-out board with markers that people move or add notes to...my goal is to prevent two people from grabbing the same marker to move or edit at the same time.

Comment: You would write `Application([myAppVariable]` (or I do not understand your question).

Comment: Please update your post to clarify what you want to do in JavaScript and what in C#... Posted code looks like valid JavaScript - not sure what you looking for in C#.

Comment: I'd like to do this entire portion in Javascript.  The code above seems to work (without single quote) but when I attempt to read the application variable later I'm not able to.

Comment: var checkID;

                checkID = "id" + o.getAttribute("S");

                if ((int)(Application['checkID'] == 0) && (Application['checkID'] != null)) {
             
                }
                else{

                }

Comment: it fails here:  if (Application([myAppVariable]) == null)           so I'm never even creating the Application variable.

Comment: `Application([myAppVariable]` might be `undefined`. In JavaScript it's normally more appriopriate to write `if (!Application(['myAppVariable'])`

Comment: Yes - Application is undefined...but even with the ! it still fails.

Comment: I've taken a different direction with this...thank you for the suggestions!